# exercise about C dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc, kill-process

I am trying to do an exercise about `malloc` and memory usage.
The text of the exercise is: Memory disaster. Reserve some memory, for example 100 kbyte at a time, in a function. Count the number of calls. This number is always the same?
I wrote this function:

```
int dis_mem(n){
    int *mem;
    mem = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (mem == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

and with a while cicle I call the function and I print the number of calls:

```
int i = 0;
while (dis_mem(25000)){ 
    i++;
}
printf("number of calls %d", i);
```

But If I execute it, after few seconds the terminal writes `killed`. I'm using geany with ubuntu 12.04.
Where I wrong?

Regards.

Comment: That's because it runs out of memory after few calls of `dis_mem`.

Comment: I supposed it, but how can I edit my code so as print the number of calls?

Comment: @linofex can you try print `i` in while? because when program run out of memory the it will not go for next instruction.it just crash.

Comment: Not needed in this trivial case, but you should remember to either check bounds on `n` or use ``calloc()` instead. `n*sizeof...` can overflow and cause security issues if it's user controlled.

Comment: Printing ' i ' in while, 'i' is at 1668980 but my pc is all block, I can't move not even the mouse! I have to restart it with the power botton.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this exercise is just to exhaust memory, but even for that, you should try not to leak memory. Each time you successfully allocate a new block, you should store the address of previous one into it. So when you exhaust, you have a chain of blocks to deallocate.

Code could be :

```
int dis_mem(n){
    void  **mem;
    void **last = NULL;
    mem = malloc(n * sizeof(void *));
    if (mem == NULL){
        while (last != NULL) {
            mem = *last;
            free(last);
            last = mem;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        *mem = last;
        last = mem;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

That way, a correct implementation of C standard library should not crash.

I could test it in a VM running Windows XP (MSVC 2008), and it runned fine, same in a VM running FreeBSD 10.1 with CLang 3.4.1 (*and no optimisation !*).

#### Explaination for the crash

In the old days, where we use true terminals or direct console, `print` use to be a simple harmless call. But now, there are emulators, that keep in memory what they display - in the Unix world, you will find xterm and alii, on Windows the CMD.EXE console - if you have exhauted all free memory and try to print a message without first freeing anything, you have a high risk that the emulator cannot get enough memory to store and process what you are sending to it and so the emulator crashes your program. That's the reason why my own version that frees all the memory **before** printing does not crash.